# How to create a service that both returns a promise and exposes a set of functions?

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angular-services

Let's suppose I have a simple service:

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.get('/something');
    }]);
```

Now whenever I inject the service into a controller, the router waits for the promise to resolve before changing the route, which is exactly what I want.

However, there doesn't seem to then be a way to return other data from the service. What if the service needs to also provide some methods? How can I do this while still maintaining the dependency behavior described above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Angular implementation to *promise pattern* `$q` to create a promise which will be resolved when the `$http.get` gets resolved, and resolve the main one with the data coming from your HTTP resource and other data and functions:

```
  angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('myService', ['$http', '$q',
    function($http, $q) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.get('/something').then(function(data) {
        deferred.resolve({
          data: data,
          doStuff: function() {}
        });
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  ]);
```

BTW, I'm not sure if the result of some HTTP request is exactly a service at all. It seems like the whole `GET` should be encapsulated by a function of your `myService` service, and call it in some controller, service, directive or wherever you need to call it, and provide a continuation with `.then` there instead.

Or, if you're using UI Router, you might be able to call a service function which returns a promise form a [route resolver](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) and it will do the job while implementing your services in the right way.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the GET request, it retrieves some data that the service needs when it first starts.

Comment: @NathanOsman Well, in general terms, I've provided you a good hint of how you would solve your issue. Read my updated answer where I've provided you even more info